# Some other perspective of reduction of structure group

Tags: fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

$(E,p,M)$ is a fiber bundle.

Suppose there exists a local trivialization $LT_1$ of $E$ such that on the overlapping areas the transition can be realized by left action of a topological group $G$ (details of the definition of structure group are omitted here), then we say that $E$ is a $G$-bundle and it has structure group $G$. Also this can induce a principle $G$-bundle $P$.

There is also another local trivialization $LT_2$ and topological group $H$ that satisfy the above and so $E$ is also a $H$-bundle and it has structure group $H$ and there is the induced principle $H$-bundle $Q$.

If $G$ and $H$ are related, e.g. there is homomorphism $H \to G$ or $H \lt G$. In this case, is the principle bundle $Q$ a reduction of structure group of $P$?

Comment: The condition in 2 is incredibly strong and hard to verify. Is that what you mean literally, or are you trying to articulate something that may be less precise?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes the purpose of 2 is not to prove something very strong, only to show that inherently $G$ and $H$ need not to be related, i.e. structure group depend on local trivialization and can a fiber bundle can have many very different structure groups.